# Displaying a friendly error message for dividing by 0

Tags: python, zero, try-except, divide

```
number1_str = input(" First number: ")
number1 = int(number1_str)

number2_str = input("Second number: ")
number2 = int(number2_str)

operation = input("Operation [+, -, *, /]: ")

if operation == "+":
    combination = number1 + number2
elif operation == "-":
    combination = number1 - number2
elif operation == "*":
    combination = number1 * number2
elif operation == "/":
    combination = number1 / number2
else:
    print(f"Answer: {combination}")
    
print()
input("Press return to continue ...")
```

Hi I'm trying to modify this code so that it displays an error message when number2 is zero and you are using the divide function to say "Sorry division by 0 is impossible" or along the lines of that. I'm very new to Python so this might be trivial for some. I've tried try and except statements however no luck. Very eager to learn from all answers!

Comment: Have a look at the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), especially [Chapter 8](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: You can try putting an if-else condition inside the divide case checking if number2 is zero then display the message; otherwise, continue your calculation.

Comment: You should also check that the input is effectively being a number, python input does no kind of validation ex ante.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
number1_str = input(" First number: ")

number2_str = input("Second number: ")

operation = input("Operation [+, -, *, /]: ")

operation_list = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

if operation in operation_list and number1_str.replace(".", "", 1).isnumeric() and number2_str.replace(".", "", 1).isnumeric():
    number1 = float(number1_str)
    number2 = float(number2_str)
    
    if operation == "+":
        combination = number1 + number2
    elif operation == "-":
        combination = number1 - number2
    elif operation == "*":
        combination = number1 * number2
    else:
        if number2 == 0:
            combination = "Sorry division by 0 is impossible"
        else:
            combination = number1 / number2
    print(f"Answer: {combination}")  
else:
    print("Error! Not valid formula")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Exception handling try-except can handle any error and if you want to make your own error message using `raise` keyword.

```
number1_str = input(" First number: ")
number1 = int(number1_str)

number2_str = input("Second number: ")
number2 = int(number2_str)

operation = input("Operation [+, -, *, /]: ")
try:
    if operation == "+":
        combination = number1 + number2
    elif operation == "-":
        combination = number1 - number2
    elif operation == "*":
        combination = number1 * number2
    elif operation == "/":
        combination = number1 / number2
    else:
        print(f"Answer: {combination}")

    print()
    input("Press return to continue ...")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Sorry division by 0 is impossible")
```